# Undefined reference trying to convert MS VS project to a makefile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, undefined-reference

I'm trying to convert a Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 project to a makefile and am running into an interesting problem. The code (in lets call it DataConstants.h) uses a few macro instances like

```
#define getDataPointer DataConstants* data = DataConstants::getInstance();
```

which is getting the warning

```
warning: unused variable ‘data’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

and the note (in another file lets call it Foo.cpp)

```
note: in expansion of macro ‘getDataPointer’
```

and down the line when things try to gt compiled, I get errors like

```
 undefined reference to `DataConstants::getInstance(std::string const&)'
```

on a line containing `getDataPointer;` in Foo.cpp. I've never gotten too complicated with Makefiles, so this may be above my pay grade, but if anyone has any ideas on what's going on I would appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way a makefile might be responsible for such error is when you forget to include a translation unit into your makefile. Since you provide very little information about your program, it isn't really possible to say much more than that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by translation unit, can you clarify that for me?

Comment: It's a source file